# PECL Package Installation Fail In Docker

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, pecl

When installing `opencensus-alpha` from PECL package manager in docker as part of dockerfile, an error is thrown `/bin/sh: pecl: not found`

## Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.17.4-alpine

RUN apk --no-cache add php7 php7-fpm php7-mysqli php7-pdo_mysql php7-json php7-openssl php7-curl \
    php7-zlib php7-xml php7-simplexml php7-phar php7-intl php7-dom php7-xmlreader php7-xmlwriter  php7-ctype php7-session \
    php7-mbstring php7-gd php-zip supervisor  libxml2-dev php7-tokenizer

RUN pecl install opencensus-alpha
```

Is there any easy way `opencensus-alpha` can be installed and enabled in a docker container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need the `php7-pear` package to get the `pecl` command, and you'll need `php-dev`, `gcc`, `musl-dev`, and `make` packages for `pecl` and `phpize` be be able to build and install other packages correctly.

Add a new `RUN` line:

```
RUN apk --no-cache add php7-pear php7-dev gcc musl-dev make
```

or amend your existing `RUN` line:

```
RUN apk --no-cache add php7 php7-fpm php7-mysqli php7-pdo_mysql php7-json php7-openssl php7-curl \
    php7-zlib php7-xml php7-simplexml php7-phar php7-intl php7-dom php7-xmlreader php7-xmlwriter  php7-ctype php7-session \
    php7-mbstring php7-gd php-zip supervisor  libxml2-dev php7-tokenizer php7-pear php7-dev gcc musl-dev make
```

Comment: this actually didn't work for PHP 8 alpine image - what worked was adding this command instead: `RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .phpize-deps-configure $PHPIZE_DEPS`